# Accessing a SMB share without a password

Tags: windows, samba

When accessing SMB shared that are password-protected, `smbclient` works just fine.

But when I'm trying to access shared that have no password protection (public shares), `smbclient` prints:

```
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

How can I access those shares?

I'm trying to access Windows 7 from my Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I believe that is not the complete error message...

Comment: @schaiba - It also says `Anonymous login successful` if it helps

Comment: Yes, it helps. Remove live essentials from the Windows 7 server and try again, it's an old bug.

Comment: @schaiba - I don't have live essentials

Comment: which version of samba you use? $smbd --version

Comment: @Yurij73 - `Version 3.6.6`

Answer (score 13):

Answering quite an old question, I can do this using smbclient like this:

```
$ smbclient //host/share -U " "%" "
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 2000] Server=[Windows 2000 LAN Manager]
smb: \>
```

This is from a fedora 21 host connecting to a solaris clone (omnios), but should be the same to a windows host.

Comment: The syntax for the -U (user) option is this: `-U|--user=username[%password]`. Therefore, this answer users the "single-space" username with a "single-space" password.

Comment: `smbclient //host/share -U guest%` worked for me.

Comment: `-U %` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

if your mount point is `/home/myuser/mountpoint` and shared folder is named `sharefolder`. You should try  `mount -t cifs //<your shareserver name or ip>/sharefolder -o username=guest,password="" /home/myuser/mountpoint`

Comment: Tried it, but I'm getting `mount error(5): Input/output error. Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)` And if I sniff with Wireshark I see I get  STATUS_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION from the server

Comment: does windows share permit folder read/write for guests?

Comment: check for sure that the full sharepath is accessible. your sharefolder and all higher level folder must be +r+x at least.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check which security option is given in your `smb.conf`. By default `security = user`  option will be enabled under `Standalone Server option` .User level of security asks for username/passwd in windows while if you keep the `security = share` it wont ask for credentials or can access share without password.
This option can also be appended to your local share definitions.

Comment: It was indeed `security = user` but it was also commented-out. Tries un-commenting it, and changed it to `security = share`, but I got the same results

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/14637-administrator-with-null-password/):

```
by default network access is denied to accounts which don't have a
password... you can change this option in the group policy
```

Well, appears it's not possible. Microsoft probably thought this is clever..

Comment: Sorry for that comment, if something goes wrong. I use a windows 2003 and XPs shares w/o any pass. Just with guest acc enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I fixed this problem for guest account access by enabling the following policy in Group Policy Management:

Default Domain Policy > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Accounts: Guest account status

Even though it is not defined, it is disabled by default and prevents enumeration of the share.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this syntax was working great on smbclient Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu to copy a file on another linux server  using smb share:

```
smbclient '//server.domain.local/share' -U 'myuser%' -c 'put "/tmp/filen_to_copy.txt" "subfolder\copied_file.txt"'
```

I think it works with Windows server w/o AD.

Answer (score 0):

@bernie had the right idea. The following command works following this syntax:

```
smbclient -L '//10.10.16.165/' -U '%' OR smbclient '//10.10.16.165/SHARE' -U '%'
```

Comment: smbclient //192.168.1.10/smb -U '%' -c 'cd \mnt\termux7\storage\emulated\0;ls'